# Symfony4 - is there possibility to call class method from Security annotation?

Tags: symfony, annotations

do you know if there is possibility to call some class static method from @Security annotation in Symfony4?

What I need is something like this:

```
@Security("is_granted(constant('App\\Voter\\ActivePluginVoter::ATTRIBUTE'), App\\Plugin\\UserManagement\\UserManagementPlugin::getRole())")
```

Comment: hi, do you have an error using `constant` like this? is it working?

Comment: constant used like this is working good :)

Comment: so what is your problem :) ?

Comment: I would like to call static method (not constant) from annotation..

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in controller method:

```
        $this->denyAccessUnlessGranted(
            ActivePluginVoter::ATTRIBUTE,
            $yourObjectHere,
            'Message when access denied'
        );
```